# See, look, watch or view? (regarding drawings/images/art)

Tags: synonyms

I run a website where the user can do two things. Draw or look at other peoples drawings.

The menu has two big buttons: [DRAW] [SEE/LOOK/WATCH/VIEW]

If I were to use it in a sentence I would go with either look or view. As in *"look at other peoples drawings"* or *"view other peoples drawings"*.

But I'm not using it in a sentence, so which word do I choose?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If this question were to apply to conversational use of these verbs, I would definitely suggest "[see](https://www.englishclub.com/vocabulary/cw-see-look-watch.htm)", since this is the verb that gives the basest meaning; i.e. the function of the eyes. First the person sees the painting, then pays attention to it, giving rise to "looking". (Consider: "See More" buttons, underneath article snippets on the web.)

However, since we are talking about the Web, and specifically about linking to content, the most common verb for menu buttons is "View". This is the verb that has seen most use in the technology world.

I haven't been able to provide any sources for my answer, other than to say that "View" is the predominant word on the Web in this type of use case.

Comment: +1; One non-rigorous source is the fact that a Google seach for [`"view your"`](https://www.google.com/#q=%22view%20your%22), shows many action-related Web links: Wells Fargo's *view your account*, Dominion Energy's *view your bill*, etc. No similar Web actions show up for searches for `"see your"`, `"watch your"`, or `"look at your"`.